# Android : Low memory error when trying to create slide show using ViewFlipper

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, slideshow, viewflipper

**SCENARIO :** I am trying to create a slideshow using viewflipper. What I am doing is setting images resource id in an integer array then I use this array to add dynamic ImageViews in viewflipper. Then I use this view flipper as a slideshow on my login page.

**PROBLEM :** Now the problem is that when I try to add more then 10 images in the array the application wont run and it show `OutOfMemory Exception`

What should I to do to add more images without this error?

Right now I am adding images from `Resource folder` but later I will get images link then I have to first download them and then add them to array.

**Here is my code :**

```
// Image resource array
int gallery_grid_Images[] = {
        R.drawable.m1, R.drawable.m2, R.drawable.m3, R.drawable.m4, R.drawable.m5, R.drawable.m6, R.drawable.m7, R.drawable.m8, R.drawable.m9, R.drawable.m10, R.drawable.m11, R.drawable.m12,
        R.drawable.m13, R.drawable.m14, R.drawable.m15, R.drawable.m16,
};

// Add child to view flipper
    for (int i = 0; i < gallery_grid_Images.length; i++) {
        setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);
    }

private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
    Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res + "");
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    image.setLayoutParams(lp);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    viewFlip_Slide_Login.addView(image);
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
10-27 13:00:43.159: E/dalvikvm-heap(7071): Out of memory on a 7259056-byte allocation.
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d5b568 self=0x41d4b9f8
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   | sysTid=7071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075398192
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   | schedstat=( 2024369000 235624000 595 ) utm=188 stm=14 core=2
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14179)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at genie.android.LoginActivity.setFlipperImage(LoginActivity.java:257)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at genie.android.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:80)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-27 13:00:43.159: I/dalvikvm(7071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 13:00:43.159: A/libc(7071): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7071 (genie.android)
```

Comment: please show error log...

Comment: what is the Avg. size of your images ?

Comment: I know this error is due to low memory. 
Average image size is 80Kb

Comment: have you installed your apk in device ?

Answer (score 3):

This may be because of the images you are using. My suggestion: Reduce the size of images. How?? Try these:

1. Reduce the resolution. A height of 700-800 pixels should be your limit.
2. Use an image compressor. My favorite: http://tinypng.org/

You can find bunch of software or online tools to reduce image size. Let's see if this helps.

Comment: As I wrote in comments average size of images is 80kB and most of them are 20 to 30 kb. I already reduced their size and I have only 15 images.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the images you are using.. Due to the drawable images it creates bitmap error.. for that refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)
and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

The images you use in `ViewFlipper` will destroy after some two pages you swiped (it depends how much you have set using setoffscreenpagelimit , by default it is 1 i guess) and it will regenerate the views but the memory referencing will not be pray for GC(Garbage Collector) hence your heap memory will keep on increasing eventually.Therefore it results in heap grow .. you check on MAT(Memeory Analyser Tool) there you can clearly check for memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you've solved this or not but use `system.gc()` in `onDestroy()` method of your activities that draws many drawables. I had the same error while opening a new activity. This solved my problem.